# How to set font for specified character?

Tags: font-lock

I don't prefer JuliaMono font, but it provides a view of one character that I want to see in my code. It is "|" that looks like a solid vertical line in some OCaml common code situation.

[image]

I prefer to use Fragment Mono. But this solid vertical feature is missing in this font.

[image]

Is it possible to set a specified font for the specified character?

---

I have resolved my specified problem by adding

```lisp
(defvar tuareg-prettify-symbols-basic-alist
  `(("|" . "│")  ; <-- added - note that the first "|" is ASCII and the second is Unicode BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL.
    ("sqrt" . ?√)
    ("cbrt" . ?∛)
```

into tuareg.el file, and

```lisp
(add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (when (functionp 'prettify-symbols-mode)
              (prettify-symbols-mode))))
```

into init.el

Of course, I have included Tuareg (to support OCaml syntax).

So, the question isn't actual for me, but I keep it open because I think it is actual in general.

Comment: I was going to suggest `set-fontset-font` but it throws the error "Can't set a font for partial ASCII range" when given a character like `?|` (or indeed any range of characters from `0x00` to `0x7F` which isn't encompassing that *entire* range).  So that's an approach which doesn't work.

Comment: I got the same error message.  (Why Emacs refuses to `set-fontset-font` ASCII char?)

Comment: The constraint is hard-coded in C and I would *guess* that there may be some display optimisations depending on it, but it's just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm just providing a workaround; it doesn't directly answer your question.)

You might want Emacs to render the ASCII `|` as a Unicode `│`.

```lisp
(add-to-list 'prettify-symbols-alist
             '("|" . ?\N{BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL}))
(prettify-symbols-mode)
```

Comment: I added your script to my init.el and it doesn't work. After that I replaced \N{BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL} with │ and it didn't help. I don't know why. I have add symbol to replace in Tuareg scrip (script to support Ocaml syntax) and my specified problem is solved (based on your idea).

Comment: @ValentynZakharenko: I just gave an example, you need to make appropriate modifications according to your own needs.  E.g., add `(add-hook 'XXX-mode-hook (lambda () my-code ...))` to your init file